# How to set indentation for first line of TextView according to another's width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I am trying to create following list view item from [Google's Material Design Guildlines](https://material.google.com/components/lists.html) for list components.

[image]

So, it should consist of different views as described:
[image]

#### My try:

[image]

I don't think it is possible to set margin for only first line of TextView.

With manual indentation:

```
android:text="                                         - I'll be in your neighborhood doing errands this weekend. Do you want to join us?"
```

[image]

How can I set indentation for `TextView Content` considering it displays HTML formatted code.

#### list_item.xml (if you wonder)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="84dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_avatar"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Saturday"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Brunch this weekend? Just making line long"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/subject_text"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/subject_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subject_text"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="                                         - I'll be in your neighborhood doing errands this weekend. Do you want to join us?"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_fullName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/subject_text"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/subject_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subject_text"
        android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Ali Connors, has long name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/subject_text"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/subject_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#9e9e9e" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take out the `user_fullName` view.  You will be putting everything in the `content` view.

You can have multiple font styles in the same `TextView`.  You will use that to get this appearance.

Unfortunately, you can't specify markup in the layout XML so you can't see how the text will look in preview mode.  You have to do it in code:

```
    contentView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\'black\'>" + username + "</font> &mdash; " + TextUtils.htmlEncode(content));
```

or another approach:

```
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    ssb.append(username);
    ssb.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Menu), 0, ssb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ssb.append(" \u2014 ");
    ssb.append(content);
    contentView.setText(ssb);
```

Comment: What if user's name is too long?

Comment: That's the beauty of it.  It doesn't matter how long the user's name is, the whole thing will get the different color or style, and the unstyled text will follow immediately after, just like HTML in a browser.  Of course, you can always put a limit on a username length and truncate it yourself before you build the entire string.

Comment: Well, I loved manually truncating thing. Actually, I did think creating only one `TextView` and displaying user's name with different color using html tags, but the length was the problem for me. How can I know when to truncate user's name on different screen sizes? Kind of setting margin from right and using android:ellipsize="end"

Comment: You could get crazy and get the `Layout` from the `TextView` and even the `TextPaint` from the `Layout` to help you measure text lengths, but my recommendation is: don't overthink it.  Come up with some reasonable lengths for different screen widths and create an integer resource i.e. `<integer name="max_username_length">30</integer>` and use different resource directories i.e. `values`, `values-w600dp`, `values-w820dp`, etc. to set different values for different screen widths.